# knowing where a func has been called

Tags: php, debugging

I have a simple function

```
function hi(){
    echo 'hi';
    echo 'this func is called from: {file} at line {line}';
}
```

is there a way to know file and line that called a func inside the func?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [debug_backtrace](http://php.net/debug_backtrace), like so:

```
function hi() {
    echo 'hi';

    $trace = debug_backtrace();
    $file = $trace[0]['file'];
    $line = $trace[0]['line'];

    echo 'this func is called from: ' . $file . ' at line ' . $line;
}

hi();
```

Note that debug_backtrace will fetch the entire call stack. The first element (`$trace[0]`) will always contain the calling line/function/file whatever.